# Can SHACL shape target any subject in a graph?

Tags: shacl

Can [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl) shape [target](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#targets) any subject in the validated graph?

The only solution that comes to mind is to use reasoning to infer that everything is `owl:Thing` and use `sh:targetClass owl:Thing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier drafts of SHACL Core had something like sh:targetAllSubjects but that got removed. Instead the SHACL Advanced Features include custom targets: https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/#SPARQLTarget

This can be used to not only target any subject but also to define a high-level vocabulary for this recurring pattern. For a reference implementation see http://datashapes.org/dash.html#AllSubjectsTarget